# Conexão Azure cai constantemente

Tags: c#, microsoft-azure

Estou usando `Visual Studio 2015`, `C#` e banco de dados `SQL Server Azure` e desenvolvendo um projeto `Windows Forms`.

Tudo funciona perfeitamente, só que, quando eu passo um certo tempo sem executar minha aplicação pra testar, recebo o erro:

> Erro de rede ou específico à instância ao estabelecer conexão com o SQL Server. O servidor não foi encontrado ou não estava acessível. 
>       Verifique se o nome da instância está correto e se o SQL Server está configurado para permitir conexões remotas. 
>       (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Não foi possível abrir uma conexão com o SQL Server) ---> 
>       `System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception (0x80004005)`: O caminho da rede não foi encontrado

o erro aparece na linha:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    -> this.usuarioTableAdapter.Fill(this.estoqueDataSet.Usuario);
}
```

Então preciso abrir o `Server Explorer`, clicar no meu `Data Connection` e clicar no botão de `refresh` aí fica normal de novo.

Sou novato tanto no `Visual Studio` quanto no `Azure` e quero saber se isso é normal, se tem risco de acontecer quando meu cliente estiver usando meu programa e se tem como "desativar" esse desligamento.

**Segue configuração do meu firewall:**

[image]

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento como eu faço pra encontrar esse arquivo?

Comment: é um windows forms, não é web

Comment: A é verdade. E como está a configuração da conexão (`"Data Source=????`)?

Comment: Data Source=***.database.windows.net;Initial Catalog=estoque;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=***;Password=***

Comment: Só configurou isto em um lugar ou tem outro lugar com outra variavel que usa o mesmo valor? Só pra ter certeza. Verifica se também se no momento que ocorre o erro `O caminho da rede não foi encontrado` o serviço do SQL Server ainda esta rodando.

Comment: rapaz, infelizmente não sei dizer quanto à outras variáveis. quanto ao SQL Server estar rodando ele está sim, pois o serviço Azure (até onde sei) fica sempre online

Comment: achei esse aqui -> Data Source=***.database.windows.net;Initial Catalog=estoque;Integrated Security=False;User ID=***;Password=********;Connect Timeout=60;Encrypt=False;TrustServerCertificate=True;ApplicationIntent=ReadWrite;MultiSubnetFailover=False

Comment: Pode ser qualquer coisa, se puder dar mais detalhes. De uma olhada no firewall, ou se tem um "Anti-DDoS"

Comment: obrigado então, vou continuar testando aqui. valeu mesmo ^^

Comment: vou alterar o connect Timeout=60 pra um número maior e ver se resolve ;)

Comment: @ItaloRodrigo mudar o TimeOut nao e a melhor maneira. Temos que resolver a causa disso. E não o responsavel por tratar o problema.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ao usar o Azure Tools com o Visual Studio, ele irá te auxiliar em várias pequenas tarefas para agilizar o desenvolvimento.

O Azure SQL, por padrão, não aceita conexões de fora dos Data Centers Azure, para se ter esse acesso, se é necessário adicionar os IPs ou range de IPs necessários na lista de excessão do [Firewall do Azure SQL](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/azure/sql-database/sql-database-configure-firewall-settings).

Pelos sintomas que você citou, me parece que o Azure Tools está adicionando seu IP nessa lista de forma automática e transparente. Acredito que, ao ficar um tempo sem testar o app, seu IP pode mudar e sair da lista de IPs, causando exatamente o erro que está recebendo.

Na lista de excessão, pode-se colocar um `*`, assim o banco irá poder receber conexão de qualquer lugar. Mas eu desencorajo a fazer, totalmente.

A melhor solução que vejo para seu cenário é, entre seu aplicação Windows e seu banco de dados Azure SQL, colocar uma interface WebAPI.

Veja esse post sobre [como criar seu primeiro serviço rest com WebAPI](http://www.eduardopires.net.br/2013/07/asp-net-web-api-meu-primeiro-servico-rest/). É bem simples e irá ajudar demais na manutebilidade da sua aplicação.

E para comunicar sua aplicação Windows com seu serviço WebAPI, eu recomendo usar [Fluent HTTP](http://tmenier.github.io/Flurl/fluent-http/). Bem simples, intuitivo e elegante.

Por ultimo, recomendo demais, ao invés de fazer sua aplicação com WinForms, que a faça com UWP - Universal Windows Platform. Windows Forms é tecnologia legado e acredito fortemente que sairá completamente de mercado em poucos anos.

Comment: meu firewall do azure está assim -> http://i66.tinypic.com/2ynmi6v.png pela lógica, deveria liberar pra todos. tem alguma outra forma de fazer/configurar essa liberação (igual você falou do *)?

Comment: to pensando seriamente em comprar hospedagem mysql e fazer meu programa usando ele :/

tem muita diferença na programacao winforms pra uwp?

Comment: @ItaloRodrigo sim, tem muita diferenca na apresentacao. Um usa XAML e outro nao. Mas UWP e o futuro dos aplicativos para Windows, e o mesmo build roda no Windows PC, em um hardware RaspberryPi, em um Windows Mobile, no Xbox One, nos tablets, etc.

Comment: @ItaloRodrigo apenas para retorno, nao consegui abrir a imagem.

Comment: veja esse link -> http://oi66.tinypic.com/2ynmi6v.jpg

Comment: outra coisa: pelo que vi o UWP gera aplicativos do windows 10 e outras plataformas. então ele irá rodar nos windows anteriores? e quanto ao banco de dados? atualmente uso Azure e penso em passar pro MySql, terei como utilizar?

Comment: @ItaloRodrigo UWP eh apenas para Windows 10 ou posterior. Mas essa ja eh outra discussao, entao abra outro topico para nao misturarmos os assuntos, pode ser? Poste aqui o link da postagem que continuamos la.

Comment: oi Thiago, já dei uma pesquisada sobre o UWP e achei muito legal. no momento irei concluir esse projeto em windows forms pois usarei em máquinas com windows antigo. fico grato pela sua atenção. abraço.